# Compiling latest OpenCV from source on OS X (with Cmake)

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake

#### My problem:

I'm using cmake to compile the latest OpenCV from SVN on Mac OS X and it's having an error at the end of the terminal output. I'm not familiar enough with Cmake to really track down the problem. What does it mean?

Here are the last several lines of output:

```
CMake Error at modules/highgui/cmake_install.cmake:38 (FILE):
  file INSTALL cannot find "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/lib/Release/libopencv_highgui.a".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/cmake_install.cmake:36 (INCLUDE)
  cmake_install.cmake:45 (INCLUDE)


make: *** [install_buildpart_0] Error 1
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
opencv_highgui:
    CompileC "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/modules/highgui/
        OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/opencv_highgui.build/
        Objects-normal/i386/cap_avfoundation.o" 
        "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_avfoundation.mm" 
        normal i386 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
install:
    PhaseScriptExecution "CMake PostBuild Rules" "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/
        OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/install.build/
        Script-10907B010907B010907B0000.sh"
```

#### How did I get here:

I downloaded the Aptogo OpenCV framework from github https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone

This comes with a bash script to compile OpenCV with Cmake, and turn the result into an XCode framework (I think):

https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone/blob/master/opencvbuild.sh

I checked out the latest OpenCV source from the SVN and ran this script on it.

#### More Errors

Found reference to cap_avfoundation.mm earlier in the log.

```
CompileC "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/modules/highgui/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/opencv_highgui.build/Objects-normal/i386/cap_avfoundation.o" modules/highgui/src/cap_avfoundation.mm normal i386 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
    cd "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/mattmontag/Unix/pvc/UTILITIES:/Users/mattmontag/Unix/pvc/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O3 -DCMAKE_INTDIR="Release" -DHAVE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DHAVE_CVCONFIG_H -DHAVE_IMAGEIO=1 -DHAVE_COCOA=1 -DHAVE_AVFOUNDATION=1 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -fexceptions -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas "-F/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/lib/Release" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/lib/Release/include" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/include" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/modules/highgui/include" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/modules/highgui/../core/include" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/modules/highgui/../imgproc/include" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/opencv/modules/highgui/src" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/modules/highgui" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/modules/highgui/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/opencv_highgui.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/modules/highgui/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/opencv_highgui.build/DerivedSources" -c "cap_avfoundation.mm" -o "/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/modules/highgui/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/opencv_highgui.build/Objects-normal/i386/cap_avfoundation.o"

cap_avfoundation.mm:59: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'
cap_avfoundation.mm:71: error: expected type-specifier before 'AVCaptureOutput'
cap_avfoundation.mm:71: error: expected `)' before 'AVCaptureOutput'
cap_avfoundation.mm:71: error: expected `;' before '*' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:101: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AVCaptureSession' with no type
cap_avfoundation.mm:101: error: expected ';' before '*' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:102: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' with no type
cap_avfoundation.mm:102: error: expected ';' before '*' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:103: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutput' with no type
cap_avfoundation.mm:103: error: expected ';' before '*' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:104: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AVCaptureDevice' with no type
cap_avfoundation.mm:104: error: expected ';' before '*' token
cap_avfoundation.mm: In constructor 'CvCaptureCAM::CvCaptureCAM(int)':
cap_avfoundation.mm:236: error: 'mCaptureSession' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:237: error: 'mCaptureDeviceInput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:238: error: 'mCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm: In member function 'void CvCaptureCAM::stopCaptureDevice()':
cap_avfoundation.mm:308: error: 'mCaptureSession' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:311: error: 'mCaptureDeviceInput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:313: error: 'mCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm: In member function 'int CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int)':
cap_avfoundation.mm:324: error: 'AVCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:324: error: 'device' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:341: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:347: error: 'mCaptureDeviceInput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:347: error: 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:348: error: 'mCaptureSession' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:348: error: 'AVCaptureSession' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:360: error: 'mCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:360: error: 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:390: error: 'AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm: In member function 'void CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight()':
cap_avfoundation.mm:427: error: 'mCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm: In member function 'virtual double CvCaptureCAM::getProperty(int)':
cap_avfoundation.mm:490: error: 'mCaptureDeviceInput' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:491: warning: no '-formatDescription' method found
cap_avfoundation.mm:491: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
cap_avfoundation.mm:491: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
cap_avfoundation.mm:491: warning: '...' as arguments.)
cap_avfoundation.mm:491: error: cannot convert 'objc_object*' to 'const opaqueCMFormatDescription*' in initialization
cap_avfoundation.mm:505: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm: In member function 'virtual bool CvCaptureCAM::setProperty(int, double)':
cap_avfoundation.mm:545: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:558: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:571: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:584: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm:597: error: 'mCaptureDevice' was not declared in this scope
cap_avfoundation.mm: At global scope:
cap_avfoundation.mm:657: error: expected type-specifier before 'AVCaptureOutput'
cap_avfoundation.mm:657: error: expected `)' before 'AVCaptureOutput'
cap_avfoundation.mm: In function 'void -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:](CaptureDelegate*, objc_selector*, <type error>)':
cap_avfoundation.mm:657: error: expected `{' before '*' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:657: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:657: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ')' token
cap_avfoundation.mm:1324: error: expected `@end' at end of input
cap_avfoundation.mm:1324: warning: incomplete implementation of class 'CaptureDelegate'
cap_avfoundation.mm:1324: warning: method definition for '-getOutput' not found
cap_avfoundation.mm:1324: warning: method definition for '-updateImage' not found
```

Comment: Seems it cannot find that files: `/Users/Matt/OpenCV/build/tmp/lib/Release/libopencv_highgui.a`.

Comment: What is the most likely reason for that?

Comment: How did you get to this point? Did you follow the instructions in [section 2 of the wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robin from Aptogo here - I wrote the build script that you are talking about. I've just tried running it with the latest OpenCV trunk (svn revision 6769) and it completes successfully. I'm using CMake version 2.8.5. You do know that the script is intended to build a framework for iOS development not OS X development, don't you? You may run into problems if you don't have the iOS SDK installed.

The error that is causing the build to fail is probably 'cannot find protocol declaration for 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'. This protocol is available in iOS 4 and Mac OS 10.7 (Lion). I'm guessing that you are trying to build on Snow Leopard without the iOS SDK installed.

EDIT for anyone else finding this on SO. The original article, pre-built OpenCV framework and build script can be found on my company's [website](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/). The pre-built framework is now built against OpenCV svn revision 7017.

Comment: Yes - I am on Snow Leopard 10.6.8. I am using XCode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2.  What's my best option?  I don't have enough drive space to upgrade to Lion right now.

Comment: So you do have the iOS SDK installed. You could try updating to the latest iOS SDK (4.3) - 4.2 is pretty old. Otherwise, I'm not sure why it is not working for you. You could also try downloading the AVCam sample from the Apple developer site and try building it - that would check that your iOS SDK installation is OK and your AVFramework headers etc haven't somehow got screwed up.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. BTW, the main reason I'm interested in the latest build is for recent developments with the stitching module. It's pretty powerful.